# Add twitter feed to SharePoint 2019 spfx app

Tags: sharepoint, spfx

I am trying to duplicate the Twitter webpart available in Office 365 with my SharePoint 2019 on-premise site.  I have a simple spfx solution and it works when I use my localhost workbench.  When I deploy this to the actual site I get an uncaught promise error and I just get a link to the Twitter feed.

In my config.json file, I have the following externals.

```
      "externals": {
    "twitter":{
      "path":"https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js",
      "globalName":"twitter"
    }
  }
```

And in my public render, I have this:

```
public render(): void {
let output = ``;
if (
  this.properties.description != null ||
  this.properties.description != undefined
) {
  output = `<h2>${this.properties.description}</h2>`;
}
output += this.properties.embedCode;
if (output != undefined) {
  this.domElement.innerHTML = output;
}
```

}

I am using publish.twitter.com to enter in the code in the webpart properties that should render.

Example:

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/Microsoft?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">Tweets by Microsoft</a> <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Does anyone know why this code works in my local workbench and not the server one?

EDIT:
I was able to get it working by adding the below code to call the Twitter widgets.js file.  I removed the external requirement as well. It does take a couple of seconds to render though, so feels a bit clunky.  If anyone has a better solution, I would like to hear about it!

```
    this.context.domElement.innerHTML = this.properties.embedCode;
SPComponentLoader.loadScript("https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js")
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Twitter 'widgets.js' loaded OK.");
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```